# In CMake, is there a way to set properties on all targets that a given target has a link dependency on?

Tags: cmake, dependency-management

In CMake, we can set target properties as either `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC`, or `INTERFACE`. Both `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` properties are inherited by any targets that depend on the current target. However, unless I'm missing something, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to define a property that must propagate in the other direction (i.e., inherited by dependencies of the current target).

Most linkers/compilers require that all linked targets have the same value for certain properties (e.g., the [exception handling model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-170)). If we want to change one of these properties for an executable it requires that it be set on all of its dependencies. Often these dependencies are submodules in our code where we can't modify their CMakeLists.txt files for our specific use-case. This leaves us with two options:

1. Set a global property (e.g., [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_FLAGS) or [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html)) that propagates to all targets in any subdirectories regardless of whether they are dependencies or not.
2. Explicitly set the properties on each dependent target using [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#command:target_compile_options). This gets excessive and repetitive depending on the number of dependencies.

It would be nice if there was a functionality that would pass properties down only to dependency targets without having to specify them all individually. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: In CMake model dependee (e.g. executable) treats its dependency (e.g. library) as something unchangable. IMPORTED libraries or ALIAS are examples of libraries which physically cannot be changed. Propagating a property from dependee to dependency is not feasible in that case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, in our case we are building the dependencies. Our current solution is option #2, but it seems like there should be a better way. Based on the first part of your response, maybe that is simply not part of CMake's model?

Answer (score 1):

For the case of compiler flags that *must* be consistent for an entire program (including parts that are dynamically linked), such as MSVC's exception handling model, I think the set-something-global approach is suitable. To me, it seems pragmatic and slightly more robust than adding flags to each third-party target one-by-one (ie. what if you forget to handle to one? or what if third-party targets are added or removed in a new version? it seems like a ripe opportunity for human error).

Setting the environment variable [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`] is a good start. You may need to do more if you are building external projects via `ExternalProject`.

A word of caution for such settings like the exception handling model: You might be tempted to hardcode this global setting inthe CMake files for your project. If your project is used by people other than just you or your company, and especially if its main component is a library and not an executable, it's good practice not to do that. Don't take away your user's ability to choose something like this (unless for some reason your library *requires* a certain exception handling model, in which case I would still leave this global setting up to them to set, provide documentation stating this, and look into emitting a CMake warning if a user doesn't comply). Instead, use a feature like [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), or only set it [if the project is the top-level project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_IS_TOP_LEVEL.html)

An intersting side note: CMake currently globally "hard-codes" `/EHsc` for MSVC builds by default. [Here's the ticket discussing this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20610)